# Find a unique $c$ such that the tangent line at $\left(c,f(c)\right)$ is horizontal

Tags: calculus

a) Find a unique $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that the graph of $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sin{\pi}x}{\pi}+3\cos^2(5x)+3\sin^2(\ln(e^{5x})$ has horizontal tangent line  at $(c,f(c))$.

b) Once you find the $c$ solve the equation $c=\frac{n}{6}$ for $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! it is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried? hint: if the tangent is horizontal its slope is $0$.

Comment: i am really not understand the problem can you help me solve this question

Comment: Use my hint - if the tangent line is horizontal, then its slope is $0$. How can we find the slope of some tangent line?

Comment: @nagu:  Hmm.  Is it fair to say that if you have done part (a), then part (b) is obvious?  You seem to have carefully quoted a problem without any evidence of thought about what you are writing.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}f(x)&=\frac{\sin{\pi}x}{\pi}+3\cos^2(5x)+3\sin^2(\ln(e^{5x}))\\&=\frac{\sin{\pi}x}{\pi}+ 3 \cos^2(5x)+3\sin^2(5x)=\frac{\sin{\pi}x}{\pi}+3\end{align*}
If it has a horizontal tangent at $x=c$, then $f'(c)=0$.
$$f'(x)=\cos\pi x$$
$$f'(c)=\cos \pi c = 0$$

> $$c=\frac{2n+1}{2}$$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$.

For $c \in [0,1]$, take $n=0$.

> $$c=\frac12$$

Then,

> $$c=\frac n6\Rightarrow n=6c=3$$

Comment: I thing it might be better to give some hints in the direction of solving rather than solve it in full details.